# /usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclapack in CentOS 7

Tags: c++, makefile, centos, ld

How should I fix this error in CentOS 7?

```
[jalal@goku c++]$ make
[ 25%] Linking CXX executable TestSVM
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lclapack
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [TestSVM] Error 1
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/TestSVM.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

I have:

```
$ lsb_release -a
LSB Version:    :core-4.1-amd64:core-4.1-noarch
Distributor ID: CentOS
Description:    CentOS Linux release 7.4.1708 (Core) 
Release:    7.4.1708
Codename:   Core
```

Here's the repo I am using:
https://github.com/sausax/pose_estimation/issues/1
https://github.com/sausax/pose_estimation

Comment: Why do you think we would know where is this library of yours installed?

Comment: The error you're getting is a generic error for the cases when a C/C++ compiler cannot find a given library, in this case "clapack" which is a C wrapper for lapack. Try: `yum install atlas atlas-devel lapack-devel blas-devel`

Answer (score 1):

Apparently this library doesn't exist for CentOS so I just searched which file contain it and removed it:

```
[jalal@goku c++]$ grep -irn "lclapack"
CMakeLists.txt:5:set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "-lcblas -lclapack")
CMakeFiles/TestSVM.dir/link.txt:1:/usr/bin/c++  -lcblas -lclapack  -rdynamic CMakeFiles/TestSVM.dir/TestSVM.cpp.o  -o TestSVM -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab 
CMakeFiles/TestSVM.dir/flags.make:5:CXX_FLAGS = -lcblas -lclapack   -std=gnu++11
CMakeFiles/TrainSVM.dir/link.txt:1:/usr/bin/c++  -lcblas -lclapack  -rdynamic CMakeFiles/TrainSVM.dir/TrainSVM.cpp.o  -o TrainSVM -lopencv_calib3d -lopencv_contrib -lopencv_core -lopencv_features2d -lopencv_flann -lopencv_highgui -lopencv_imgproc -lopencv_legacy -lopencv_ml -lopencv_objdetect -lopencv_photo -lopencv_stitching -lopencv_superres -lopencv_ts -lopencv_video -lopencv_videostab 
CMakeFiles/TrainSVM.dir/flags.make:5:CXX_FLAGS = -lcblas -lclapack   -std=gnu++11
```

A similar solution is also suggested here https://github.com/SciRuby/nmatrix/commit/d126005ca9ce8339c54a80accaa835904f304f6c

Or better yet remove it from CMakeLists.txt

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "-lcblas -lclapack")
```

convert to

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS  "-lcblas")
```